# How can I only UPDATE if the user was created?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008

I got A cursor with some ifs like this one:

```
 IF @ROLE='RW' 
            BEGIN
                SET @COMMAND ='
                USE '+QUOTENAME(@DATABASE)+'
                CREATE USER '+QUOTENAME(@LOGIN_ACESSO)+' FOR LOGIN '+QUOTENAME(@LOGIN_ACESSO)+' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[DBO]'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'
                USE '+QUOTENAME(@DATABASE)+'
                ALTER ROLE [DB_DATAREADER] ADD MEMBER '+QUOTENAME(@LOGIN_ACESSO)+'
                ALTER ROLE [DB_DATAWRITER] ADD MEMBER '+QUOTENAME(@LOGIN_ACESSO)
            END

PRINT @COMMAND
EXECUTE (@COMMAND)

UPDATE TBL_LOGINPERMISSAO SET CRIADO =1 WHERE [ID]=@ID
```

But obviously, even if the user was not created, I update TBL_LOGINPERMISSAO. How can I update only if the user was created? even copying this update on all ifs, it does not work, because even not creating the user will reach the UPDATE.

is this a case for try/catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the `UPDATE` only if the user `EXISTS` like this:

```
SET @COMMAND = '
    IF EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@DATABASE) + '.sys.sysusers
      WHERE name = ''' + @LOGIN_ACESSO + '''
    )
    BEGIN
      UPDATE TBL_LOGINPERMISSAO SET CRIADO = 1 WHERE [ID] = ' + CAST(@ID AS nvarchar(max)) + '
    END'
EXEC (@COMMAND)
```

You'll need to add quotes around the `@ID` part if it not a numeric value, e.g. (n)varchar or guid.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account that you need to check the user for a specific database,
you could do something like this?

```
SET @COMMAND =
'USE '+@DATABASE+' 
 SELECT name FROM sys.sysusers WHERE name = '''+@LOGIN_ACESSO+''''
DECLARE @t TABLE (LOGIN_ACESSO NVARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @t 
EXECUTE  (@COMMAND)
IF exists (select LOGIN_ACESSO from @t)
BEGIN
    UPDATE TBL_LOGINPERMISSAO SET CRIADO =1 WHERE [ID]=@ID
END
```